# How to prepend a string to a column in csv

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, csv

I have a csv with 5 columns in `in.csv` and I want to prepend all the data in column 2 with "text" in this same file such that the row

```
data1 data2 data3 data4 data5
```

becomes

```
data1 textdata2 data3 data4 data5
```

I thought using regex might be a good idea, but I'm not sure how to proceed

Edit:

After proceeding according to bigbounty's answer, I used the following script:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("in.csv")
df["id_str"] = str("text" + str(df["id_str"]))
df.to_csv("new_in.csv", index=False)
```

My `in.out` file is like:

```
s_no,id_str,screen_name
1,1.15017060743203E+018,lorem
2,1.15015544419693E+018,ipsum
3,1.15015089995785E+018,dolor
4,1.15015054311063E+018,sit
```

After running the script, the `new_in.csv` file is:

```
s_no,id_str,screen_name
1,"text0    1.150171e+18
1    1.150155e+18
2    1.150151e+18
3    1.150151e+18
Name: id_str, dtype: float64",lorem
2,"text0    1.150171e+18
1    1.150155e+18
2    1.150151e+18
3    1.150151e+18
Name: id_str, dtype: float64",ipsum
3,"text0    1.150171e+18
1    1.150155e+18
2    1.150151e+18
3    1.150151e+18
Name: id_str, dtype: float64",dolor
4,"text0    1.150171e+18
1    1.150155e+18
2    1.150151e+18
3    1.150151e+18
Name: id_str, dtype: float64",sit
```

Whereas it should be:

```
s_no,id_str,screen_name
1,text1.15017060743203E+018,lorem
2,text1.15015544419693E+018,ipsum
3,text1.15015089995785E+018,dolor
4,text1.15015054311063E+018,sit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can easily be done using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("in.csv")
df["data2"] = "text" + df["data2"].astype(str)
df.to_csv("new_in.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks but "data2" won't be the same for all rows. I want to prepend "text" to all the data entries in column 2. Something along the lines of iterating through all the rows, but I'm not sure how to achieve that


Edit: Thanks a lot, it worked after changing `data2` to `column2`

Comment: @Eagle Upvote and accept the answer if it has helped you

Comment: Thanks it did help but since the data in `column2` was a number, I used `df["id_str"] = str("text" + str(df["id_str"]))`, but it messed up the output. I'll edit the question to show the same issue

Comment: Use `df["data2"] = "text" + df["data2"].astype(str)`

Comment: thanks it works now, could you explain what was happening with `str("text" + str(df["id_str"]))`

Comment: `str(df["id_str"])` will convert all the rows in the column to a single string, hence it will get messed up

Comment: You can use `"text" + df.id_str.map(lambda x: '{:.0f}'.format(x))`

Comment: thanks a lot, I used `df = pd.read_csv("in.csv", dtype={'INPUT: Extra 1':np.object_})` before your suggestion, but not using numpy seems better

Comment: You don't need to give `dtype` unless you want some specific type. pandas will try to infer for you

Answer (score 1):

- Using the `csv` module

```py
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r+', newline='') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f))  # produces a list of lists
    for i, r in enumerate(data):
        if i > 0:  # presumes the first list is a header and skips it
            r[1] = 'text' + r[1]  # add text to the front of the text at index 1
    f.seek(0)  # find the beginning of the file
    writer = csv.writer(f)  
    writer.writerows(data)  # write the new data back to the file

# the resulting text file
s_no,id_str,screen_name
1,text1.15017060743203E+018,lorem
2,text1.15015544419693E+018,ipsum
3,text1.15015089995785E+018,dolor
4,text1.15015054311063E+018,sit
```

- Using pandas
- This solution is agnostic of any column names because it uses column index.

  - [`pandas.DataFrame.iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

# read the file set the column at index 1 as str
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', dtype={1: str})

# add text to the column at index 1
df.iloc[:, 1] = 'text' + df.iloc[:, 1]

# write to csv
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)

# resulting csv
s_no,id_str,screen_name
1,text1.15017060743203E+018,lorem
2,text1.15015544419693E+018,ipsum
3,text1.15015089995785E+018,dolor
4,text1.15015054311063E+018,sit
```